# Prevent click action on all elements inside body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am writing a WYSWIG inline editor, all elements are editable besides editor menu elements.

**JS Code**

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("mousedown", function(e) {

        if($(e).target().is(".ignore")) {
            return;
        }

        //I hope it will stop the event to bubble up
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body").on("click", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<a href="http://google">Google</a>
<button onclick="window.location.url='https://www.amazon.com'">Amazon</button>
<button onclick="alert('Ignore unbind')" class="ignore">Ignore</button>

<iframe src="http://w3schools.org" />
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/e7gbm557/2/

**Problem**

In the above one, click event is prevented for the button element but if you click the anchor tag inside the iframe it takes me into the link url.

Not only for anchor tags inside iframe, it happen for some other elements too.

What is the proper way to prevent click action to all elements inside a body except some elements?

Comment: You can't prevent events on a third party page loaded into iframe. You could create a transparent cover element over the iframe, that might solve the issue.

Comment: @Teemu what happen if an element inside a body binds click event and calls event.stopPropagation(), my parent click event binding won't be called. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `click` event, not the `mousedown` event:

```
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
    //I hope it will stop the event to bubble up
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7gbm557/4).

Furthermore your first `button` element's `onclick` doesn't really do anything anyway. Your `e.preventDefault()` isn't working on that, because there's simply nothing to prevent. By default there is no `url` property assigned to `window.location`, you're simply adding this to `window.location`. This should have simply been:

```
<button onclick="window.location='https://www.amazon.com'">Amazon</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot James, If a child element binds click event and calls event.stopPropagation(), it won't reach the parent binding. Please correct me If I am wrong.